# Why do I get an error message related to building wheels while installing a package?

Tags: python, lda, python-wheel

I'm trying to install a package (in my case `guidedlda`), but the installation is not working. I entered `pip install guidedlda`, but I got the following error message

```
pip install guidedlda

Collecting guidedlda
  Using cached guidedlda-2.0.0.dev22.tar.gz (2.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from guidedlda) (1.23.5)
Building wheels for collected packages: guidedlda
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for guidedlda (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for guidedlda
  Running setup.py clean for guidedlda
Failed to build guidedlda
ERROR: Could not build wheels for guidedlda, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried other ways to install the package but always got the same error message. I was also able to install other packages without any problems.

I use Google [Colaboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Industry_adoption) with Python 3.10.12.

Comment: There are issues for this in the GuidedLDA repo – maybe one of them helps you too. The project seems pretty abandoned though. https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA/issues

Comment: have you tried the recommendation from the officials documentation, and also mention the  OS and it's version  in case `pip install guidedlda`   fails the steps below are recommended  `https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA
cd GuidedLDA
sh build_dist.sh
python setup.py sdist
pip install -e .` if you're using windows consider running cmd in Administrative mode

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/guidedlda/), the latest version of `guidedlda 2.0.0.dev22` was released on 2017-10-27 and it supports only Python 3.4 - 3.6, but you are using Python 3.10.12.

The best bet is to use a lower version of Python supported by `guidedlda`, and I'll also encourage you to visit the link above and skim through it.

Comment: (but using a desperately out-of-date version of Python is not a great idea either.)

Comment: If OP can find another similar package, that would help. Sometimes they just want to use the package in question. Another alternative would be to raise an issue with the developers for a more stable release.

Comment: There's apparently a PR that should fix this (by re-Cythonizing the .pyx file to .c): https://github.com/vi3k6i5/GuidedLDA/pull/56

Comment: yes, that's the way to go. OP can have a look as others are having similar challenges.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that you’re using an unsupported version of Python for whatever package you are trying to install. Check what version that package supports and try to use that version of Python.